# Error on file save: "Opening output file: resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

About 10% of the time, when I attempt to save my file in Emacs I get the following error:

```
Opening output file: resource temporarily unavailable,
```

I'm currently using Emacs GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2) on
Ubuntu 12.04.  I've also verified that this issue occurs logged in as a different user and using Emacs 23.3.1.

This issue gets to be a real pain when I make a fix, attempt to save, and then wonder why my fix didn't happen.... only to find out later that the Emacs save was never successful.
If I notice it happen, I'll keep hitting Ctrl-x Ctrl-s until a save actually goes through (takes a few times).

Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how to prevent it?

Update:
(More info per request)

- I'm currently on a Ruby on Rails project and have been getting the error while editing a variety of file types *.rb, *js.coffee, *js.erb, *html.erb, etc.
- The files I receive the error on are always files local to my machine.  I haven't tested remote files.
- If I look at the *messages buffer, for every time the error message occurred, the error is prefixed with: save-buffer-2

Update 2:
Issue is encountered in multiple Emacs versions by multiple users.

Update 3:
This doesn't appear to be an Emacs specific issue as I now get the occasional "Unable to save" popup window while attempting to save files in Sublime-text editor.

Comment: More info might help. Is the file local or remote? Does it matter which file?

Comment: Which file system?  Is your disk healthy?

Comment: The file system type is ext3 and it's checked on every boot. This issue has now been reported by at least 3 of my colleagues.  All of our disks appear healthy.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bug from emacs (`M-x report-emacs-bug`), some issue with your filesystem (I assume this is not the case because most likely you checked if problem happens with other editors), or some process in your local setup messing with your files.

For testing if the later is the case, you could try to eval this and then reproduce the problem:

```
(defadvice save-buffer (around find-shenanigan activate)
  (condition-case ()
      ad-do-it
    (error
     (shell-command (format "lsof -V %s" (buffer-file-name)) "*debug-issue*"))))
```

What this does is every time the save operation fails, it executes a command that takes a picture of the processes that have your file opened.  If you see any process, you know who investigate.  man lsof will help with the details.

Note: Does the problem happen also with emacs -Q?

**EDIT**: if you can use sudo without password (NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers), replace "lsof" with "sudo lsof"
**EDIT**: I redirected the output of the lsof to a buffer named `*debug-issue*`; check that buffer if error.

Comment: I'm assuming that I accomplish "eval this" by adding the "defadvice" code to my .emacs file.  But after doing that, I now get "(Shell command failed with code 1 and no output)" instead of the resource error.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I assume you have lsof installed.  I edited the answer to make lsof be more verbose and redirect errors to output.  Hopefully this way some there is some output to yield some clue.

Comment: I really appreciate your help in tracking this issue down.  I do have lsof installed and I've included your latest updates in my .emacs file.... however I still keep getting the same new error when the save fails: "(Shell command failed with code 1 and no output)".  FWIW, I've verified that I can run lsof manually in emacs after entering the shell command mode with M-!

Comment: And I just realized I have a bunch of files name "1" in various subdirectories where file saves have failed :).
They contain the following:<br/>
`lsof: status error on 2: No such file or directory<br/>
 lsof: no file use located: /tmp/file_Im_trying_to_save`

Comment: Ok, redirection is not working as I expected :-). I assume you were trying to save the file in /tmp dir.  If not, you might have some package trying to do something in that dir.  Please try with emacs -Q just to be sure (after loading emacs -Q, eval the code I wrote).  The error you see in the files named 1 means that lsof cannot see that file either (that would be a problem in your filesystem)

Comment: @TwiceB I changed the redirection to use a specific buffer.

Comment: I made the update and now I get a `no file use located` message in the debug buffer.  I updated the main question to reflect a recent test with a different version of Emacs (happens in both 23 and 24).  I'll attempt now to run with Emacs -Q as well as test with other editors.  Thanks again.

Comment: I should have checked out other text editors as you earlier suggested.  I was able to recreate the issue a couple times using sublime-text.  So it's probably a file system issue as you suspected.  Thanks for helping my track this down.